# Travel insurer asking about my other insurance products

Tags: insurance, uk-residents

My travel insurer is asking for details of my home insurance and says it is normal to share the cost of the claim. Is that normal?

I don't think my home insurance has any relevant cover (I am claiming for curtailment due to illness of a non traveller).

Comment: This is normal since home insurance often covers part of the emergency expenses accumulated during travel, but you don't have to answer. Also, this seems to be an offtopic.

Comment: This might be relevant if you were claiming for theft of an object and they are hoping you have all-risks on your home insurance but it does not seem relevant for illness cover.

Comment: I'm in the insurance industry in Canada.  Your insurer should only need documentation of your property insurance coverage if they are covering (or considering) property, e.g. lost baggage.  Homeowenr's insurance would not cover trip cancellation.  You could always get a letter/memo from your insurer or broker confirming your policy does not cover such losses.  You shouldn't need it, but it might be the path of least resistance.

Comment: In which country are you purchasing the insurance?